# Accessing functions inner variables in node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

I an a newbie to javascript/nodejs. I am currently trying to access data from one of the open weather API's using the request something like

`var url='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${apikey}';
  resBody=request(url, function(err,res,body){
return body}`

when I do a `console.log(body)` inside the function i get the expected results but same is not available on `console.log(resBody)` the results are different.

What am I missing. Can you please help here.

Comment: Well yes. `resBody = request(stuff)`, that returns a `request` operation (an object). Whereas `body` is the _result_ of the request operation, after it's completed. Requests and calls are asynchronous.

Comment: That `return` does not do what you think it is doing. Need to learn the basics of promises and asynchronous requests